# No me anda el drop table con los Statement o PreparedStatement

Tags: java

tengo este código para borrar una tabla, de la misma manera, tengo otros dos para insertar datos o borrarlos y andan barbaro, pero esta de borrar tabla es imposible, no se que pasa, ya usé incluso con Statement y nada.

```
      PreparedStatement pst;
            String borrarTablaSql= "drop table if exists empleados_?";
            pst= con.prepareStatement(borrarTablaSql);
            pst.setString(1, usuarioAdmin);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
```

Comment: ¿Usas MySQL, Postgresql o cuál?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba utilizando este fragmento de codigo :

```
PreparedStatement dropTable = cnx.prepareStatement(
String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s", "features"));
dropTable.execute();
```

Comment: Hola José Felipe, esta respuesta es la correcta, no sé porqué no me funcionaba de la otra marea, pero de esta va excelente. Te agradezco tu molestia y disculpá la tardanza en responder sos un genio!